# Monthly sales in product list query

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me solve my complicated sql request?

I have an html page with a product list and to every item i want to join loading and sales information for last 4 months.

My desired result is: 
Item1 - Month0 (12 in, 0 out), Month-1 (33 in, 36 out)......
Item2 - Month0 (10 in, 30 out), Month-1 (0 in, 66 out)......

**My SQL Queries:**

Products(simplified) in method "getProducts":

```
Select item_id, item_name
From Products
```

Loading

```
SELECT item_id, CONCAT(YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS YearMonth,SUM(load_qty) AS total,
            FROM loading
            GROUP BY YearMonth
            WHERE item_id = ?
            ORDER BY YearMonth DESC ', array($productId));
```

Sales

```
SELECT item_id, CONCAT(YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS YearMonth,SUM(load_qty) AS total,
            FROM sales
            GROUP BY YearMonth
            WHERE item_id = ?
            ORDER BY YearMonth DESC ', array($productId));
```

Then I got PHP file to call SQL method:

```
$products = $productManager->getProducts();
$this->data['portalProducts'] = $portalProducts;
```

And final HTML file with product list:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo date("Y - m", strtotime("now"))?></td> //current month
        <td>//here goes current month load</td>
        <td>//here goes current month sale</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo date("Y - m", strtotime("-1 month"))?></td> //last month
        <td>//here goes last month load</td>
        <td>//here goes last month sale</td>
    </tr>
    ..............
</table>
```

Is it possible to combine all of the results from the above queries into one request and then display it as I mentioned in the beginning...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your SQL queries as follows:

```
SELECT p.item_id, p.item_name, cal.year_month, COALESCE( q_in.total, 0 ) AS qty_in, COALESCE( q_out.total, 0 ) AS qty_out
FROM Products AS p
    INNER JOIN
                ( SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW())) AS `year_month`
                UNION
                SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS `year_month` ) AS `cal`
            ON 1 = 1
        LEFT JOIN
                    ( SELECT `item_id`, CONCAT(YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS `year_month`, SUM(`load_qty`) AS `total`,
                    FROM loading
                    WHERE (`load_date` BETWEEN LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW())
                    GROUP BY `item_id`, YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS q_in
                ON p.item_id = q_in.item_id AND cal.year_month = q_in.year_month
        LEFT JOIN
                    ( SELECT item_id, CONCAT(YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS `year_month`, SUM(`load_qty`) AS `total`,
                    FROM sales
                    WHERE (`load_date` BETWEEN LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW())
                    GROUP BY `item_id`, YEAR(`load_date`), MONTH(`load_date`)) AS q_out
                ON p.item_id = q_out.item_id AND cal.year_month = q_out.year_month
ORDER BY p.item_id, p.item_name, q_in.year_month
```

Output example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| item_id | item_name | year_month | qty_in | qty_out |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | blah      | 201604     | 0      | 16      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | blah      | 201605     | 12     | 16      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

### Explanation:

I have used "Calendar" sub-query to generate a list of months so that your output will always have a row for the current and the previous months even when total quantity for a given month is 0 in and 0 out:

```
( SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW())) AS YearMonth
                            UNION
                            SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS YearMonth ) AS Cal
```

Afterwards I use a left join to join the queries for "loading" and "sales".

I have added a

```
WHERE (load_date BETWEEN LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW())
```

to each of the sub-queries to restrict the calculation to current and last month only. This is to improve performance.

**Note:** I have not tested the query in MySQL

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your advice. I tried it and something must be wrong. I see 2 bugs as a minimum (Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'QIn.YearMonth' in 'field list''......Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM portal_loading WHERE (load_date BETWEEN LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL). Im not so advanced to fix it now, can you please check query once again :-) Thanks

Comment: ......and one more thing, this solution I guess I can use in product detail, but I dont think its suitable for product list, every item must be displayed only once...Im my eyes its too much for one universal query and has to be solved different way :-/

Comment: @Frezik, I don't have MySQL installed so apologies for syntax errors. Yesterday I have tried SQL Fiddle but it is a pain and did not help. RE: "and one more thing" you can change the way you loop through the records in PHP e.g. create a variable that will store item_id of the last record and in each loop check if record item_id is the same as that in the variable. If the same that add an HTML row with month data if not the same start a new table.